# Pandas: extend mask to set regions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Boolean mask in "python pandas", where I want to widen (smear?) each "True" sample. Suppose I have the following:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': [False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False]})
```

So the "True" mask looks like:

```
mask = data[data.col1 == True]
>>> mask
   col1
1  True
6  True
```

I would like to have:

```
>>> mask
   col1
0  True
1  True
2  True
5  True
6  True
7  True
```

How can I set the neighboring indices up to a distance of (say) 1 to "True" as well? I could write a for-loop, no thing. But that feels wrong.

Hints? Tips? Keywords?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is to use `rolling` and `max`:

```
n=1
window = n*2 + 1
data.col1.rolling(window, center=True, min_periods=1).max().astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool

print(mask)

   col1
0  True
1  True
2  True
5  True
6  True
7  True
```